# Как с помощью XMLHTTPRequest посылать запросы в цикле?

Tags: post, javascript, циклы

Имеется следующий код асинхронного запрос:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/service.ashx", true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
    clearTimeout(timeout); /*очистить таймаут при наступлении readyState 4*/
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //запрос прошел удачно, некие манипуляции с xmlhttp.responseText
    } else {
        handleError(xmlhttp.statusText) // вызвать обработчик ошибки с текстом ответа
    }
}
xmlhttp.send('action=search');
var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    xmlhttp.abort();
    handleError("Time over")
}, 10000); /*таймаут*/
```

Как этот запрос можно завернуть в цикл, чтобы корректно срабатывал timeout и clearTimeout(timeout)? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такое решение, ваш код обернут в функцию, которую можно вызывать в цикле, перебирая массив с данными.

```
   // Массив данных
    var arr = ['action=search','action=search2','action=search3','action=search4'];
    // Цикл в котором осуществляем перебор данных
    for(var i = 0; l = arr.length, i < l; ++i){
        // Вызываем функцию с запросами к серверу
        request(data[i]);
    };

    function request(data){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "/service.ashx", true);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // вызов колбека например
            } else {
                handleError(xmlhttp.statusText)
            };
        };
        xmlhttp.send(data); // Тут ваши данные запроса
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            xmlhttp.abort();
            handleError("Time over")
        }, 10000);
    };
```

А  собственно таймер там корректно описан, только вместо handleError должен быть ваш обработчик ошибки.

Comment: но xmlhttp.abort() будет уничтожать нужный объект или как придется???

Comment: Будет! через 10 секунд. если ответ от сервера не получен